# How to make the format of a DateField to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: java-me, datefield

There is a DateField in my Form and I want the field value to be displayed in the format dd/mm/yyyy after dismissing ( choosing ) a date from the date-popup. How to achieve that ?

Comment: You already asked [same type of question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773274/how-to-create-a-field-of-format-dd-yyyy). right? then why you asking again?

Comment: @Bharath : the first question did not relate to a DateField. But this one relates to DateField !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't change the format of date in `DateField` component in java-me.

Answer (score 0):

as already noted MIDP 2 does not provide API for that.

To simulate behavior like you describe, one has to manually convert the `DateField`'s date to string like that and, say, put it into item label (by `itemStateChanged` event).

Or, if there's no need to let user choose date after done once, one can even replace date field with `StringItem` containing that *dd/mm/yyyy*.